# How to get horizontal edges between nodes of two or more clusters?

Tags: graphviz

I have to clusters A and B with 3 nodes each. I need to connect nodes between clusters in a bipartite way.

This code:

```
digraph G {

subgraph cluster_A {
    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    edge [style=invisible,dir=none];
    node [style=filled,color=white];
    a1 -> a2 -> a3;
}

subgraph cluster_B {
    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    edge [style=invisible,dir=none];
    node [style=filled,color=white];
    b1 -> b2 -> b3;
}
a1 -> b1;
a2 -> b2;
a3 -> b3;
}
```

does almost what I want with **dot** but cluster B is not at the same level as cluster A. It is offset by some amount below A.

How can I prevent this offset and have both clusters at the same level?

Comment: Are you saying that you simply want horizontal connections between clusters a and b?

Comment: That is correct. I just want 1-to-1 horizontal connections between nodes of cluster A and nodes of cluster B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular graph, you could use

```
edge[constraint=false];
```

to not have the edges between the nodes influence the layout:

```
digraph G {
  subgraph cluster_A {
      style=filled;
      color=lightgrey;
      edge [style=invisible,dir=none];
      node [style=filled,color=white];
      a1 -> a2 -> a3;
  }

  subgraph cluster_B {
      style=filled;
      color=lightgrey;
      edge [style=invisible,dir=none];
      node [style=filled,color=white];
      b1 -> b2 -> b3;
  }

  edge[constraint=false];
  a1 -> b1;
  a2 -> b2;
  a3 -> b3;
}
```

[image: graphviz output]